# how can you pulse a progress bar in Qt?

Tags: qt, progress-bar

Is there a way of using CSS or something else to make a pulsing QProgressBar in pyqt as illustrated below?

[image]

The default progress bar has an animation when using the windows vista theme, but I'm not sure how to edit it.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicseffect.html#details

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpropertyanimation.html

This should get you what you want.  Combine the dropshadow effect (large blur radius + green + zero offset) with a looping `QPropertyAnimation` (adjusting the opacity property), and you have your flashing, glowing progress bar.

Comment: Those links all seem to go to the same page.

Comment: @CardinalSystem updated links.  :)